# Initialize another project (WinForms App) from current ASP.NET MVC 5 Web App

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to initialize another project which is a web form application project from my current project ASP.NET MVC5 web application.

This web form application consist of a main method which initialize the whole project and I only need to initialize this project once a button from the current project (ASP.NET MVC5 web application) is clicked.

Any idea how I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both are in the same domain, you may expose your specific code/method via a a [ashx handle](http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx)r and then can be called from your MVC project button click event.

Invoking the handler from click event on the button with id `invokeWebFormBtn` (using jQuery)

```
$(function(){

  $("#invokeWebFormBtn").click(function(e){

    var url="/ReplacePathToYourHandlerHere";
    $.post(url);

  });

});
```